# why should we parse process.env value

Tags: webpack

I noticed in many `config.js` files that people use `parseInt(process.env.value, 10)` but it works also without this parse
anyone know use case for this? or downsides?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

They do that because the value they want is usually an integer and it is translated by webpack to a string. That is why.

Comment: thanks for your answer @PlayMa256 so you are saying it will be translated to string with webpack, even if the original value was a string?, just curious because I removed the `parse` and webpack continue to work as usual!

Comment: depends on how you defined it using `DefinePlugin`. Usually it has stringify on it.